# How to get an url to a menuitem from an article id in joomla 1.6?

Tags: joomla, seo, url-routing, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6

I'm writing a module that has articles. I would like these article to end with the "read more" button. This button should redirect to a menuitem pointing to the full article if such a menuitem exists, or to the article (as in component=com_content&id=... etc.) if this is not the case.

Right now I'm using JRoute with the id:

```
$url = JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$article->id );
```

but this returns the following url:

```
$url  = "http://example.com/option=com_content&view=article&id=1"
```

This points to the correct article, but is not search-engine friendly (it is on, with .htaccess support) AND it leads to a different page than my menuitem pointing to the article.

I'm sure it has to do something with JRoute but I can't find any resource on how to make this work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the ComponentHelperRoute:

```
$link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->slug, $article->catslug, $article->sectionid));
```

Comment: thanks, after messing around with it a bit and doing some more research on the getArticleRoute I found this piece of code that eventually made it work for my case: $url = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->id, $article->catid));